# How to draw bright color background in linux tty?

Tags: tty, colors

I'm using ubuntu18.04 `/dev/tty3`(ctrl-alt-f3).

```
tput colors
--------
8
```

I can draw bright foreground red:

```
tput bold; tput setaf 1; echo 'xxxxxx'
echo -e '\e[91mxxxxxx'
```

But it doesn't work for background:

```
tput bold; tput setab 1; echo 'xxxxxx'
echo -e '\e[101mxxxxxx'
```

this [page](https://tools.paco.bg/14/#terminals_compatibility) says one can draw bright background with `blink`, so i try to do this:

```
tput blink; tput setab 1; echo 'xxxxxx'
echo -e '\e[5;41mxxxxxx'
echo -e '\e[5;101mxxxxxx'
```

none works.

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) says sometimes you can draw bright color with `reverse`, so i try to do this:

```
tput rev; tput bold; tput setaf 1; echo 'xxxxxx'
echo -e '\e[7;31mxxxxxx'
```

none works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` to config console, `man console-setup` says:

> There are two kinds of codesets - small (up to 256 symbols) and big (up to 512 
>     symbols).  Only small codesets can be used on FreeBSD.  When the screen is in 
>     text mode (i.e. framebuffer is  not
>           used) then fonts covering big codesets will reduce the number of available 
>     foreground colors.

Choose a small codeset fixed the problem, the `blink` attribute will draw background in bright color.

Comment: Changing colours with either blinking or bold is, strictly, a mis-use of terminfo based merely upon how VGA display hardware, and kernel virtual terminals in several operating systems for PCs having VGA display hardwares, happens to work.  Linux KVTs have understood the AIXterm SGR 90-97,100-107 renditions for years, now.  They usually don't even use VGA display adapter text mode, now.

Comment: @JdeBP  They work fine in 256 color terminal, but not in `tty`(ctrl-alt-f3). My test shows different result, 90-97 always work, 100-107 never works, not even after  I use a small codeset and  change `TERM` to `linux-16color`. The output of `tput setab 9` in  `linux-16color` include the `blink` attribute: `\e[41;5m`, this is the only way I know that get bright background rendition in `tty`, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes.  The `setab` and `setaf` capabilities do not employ the AIXterm SGR sequences.  Emitting them directly with `printf` or some such will work, however.  The kernel terminal emulator has understood them from (as I understand it) Linux version 4.8 onwards.  Amusingly, it has actually understood the SGR control sequences for 256-colour indexed colour and 24-bit RGB direct colour for longer, since the time of Linux 3.16.

Comment: @JdeBP To be honest, this is the first time I hear `AIxterm`, I'm a newbie in these area, I searched a bit and find this [page](https://unix-junkie.github.io/christmas/Comparison%20of%20Terminal%20Emulators%20-%20Colour%20Support.html), lots of them work as you described (I tried it in `xterm-16color`).